# How to create an array of html textbox dynamically with data in it from database vb.net?

Tags: html, vb.net

What I want to do here is that I would have an array of textbox dynamically create according to the number of rows in my database and inside the textbox would have values from database such as "john". The purpose for this is so that the user is able to update it easily. Can someone please help ?

Well I though of using for each statement but I have trouble displaying the values in all the textbox. Here is the example which will display the html textbox:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sql As String = "Select * from Employee WHERE date is null"
    Dim EmployeeDt As DataTable = DBadapter.GetDataTable(sql)
    Dim i = 0
            For Each row As DataRow In EmployeeDt.Rows

                    Literal1.Text += "<table><tr><td>"
                    Literal1.Text += "<input id='Text" & i & "' type='text' />"
                    Literal1.Text += "</td></tr></table>"

                i += 1

            Next
End sub
```

But I have no idea how I'm going to display the values in the textboxes.

Comment: I'm having a hard time working out what your description means and also how the code snippit relates to it. Can you please have a go at editing your question to make it clearer?

Comment: Here is the image to get a better picture : http://vb.net-informations.com/gui/dynamic-controls-vb.htm

Comment: I would like it to display something like the image just that it would not be textbox1, textbox2 ... but data from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Literal1.Text += "<input id='Text" & i & "' type='text' value='" & some_value & "'/>"
```

You will also need to add:

```
runat="server"
```

if you want to access the textbox from the code behind.